# Could not file Archlinux env file

Tags: environment-variables, zsh, archlinux

Could I please have some assistance on finding my env file?

---

Now I am using zsh and installed Maven successfully. Then I add Maven into the Environment variable like this:

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.8.4 
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin 
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m 
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

It is successful too. Now I can run "mvn -version".

Then I checked those paths by using "printenv". They are all there. For example, the Maven is like:

PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.8.7/

Then I tried to find where I add those Paths to. I tried the following:

/etc/environment
~/.bashrc
~/.pam_environment
~/.xprofile
~/.zshrc

However, I could not find "PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.8.7/" in any of above.

So where could it be stored in? Where is the exact env file storing these paths?

So where could it be stored in? Where is the exact env file storing these paths?

Comment: `/usr/local` sounds like you installed it manually, which is not recommended in Arch. Why not just use the official [community/maven](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/any/maven/)? `sudo pacman -S maven`

Comment: I didn't think that part yet. It's a good idea to do it via pacman. But today I'm just trying to find out the relevant env file.